Is Mills' constant proven to be within a certain range?
Is there a statement that says, like for example, “$\theta < 10^{100}$ no matter if the Riemann hypothesis is true”? Mills’ constant is calculated to be around $1.306$ if the Riemann hypothesis is true, so is the value at least given a range (no matter if the hypothesis is true or otherwise)? For example, the value of the de Bruijn–Newman constant is unknown, but it is known that the constant is less than $0.2$. How about Mills’ constant? Is it proven to be, for example, $10$ or less or is it possible that it is larger than a googolplex?
